# New administrator account has limited access

Tags: user-account

I have an admin account which has a typo in it's account name and I wanted to fix it. So I created a different admin account so that I can rename the account name and home folder name from that account.

But when I logged in from the second admin account, my macbook air (macOS mojave) is exhibiting weird behavior, for example, the dock has lost its animation, taping on trackpad doesn't serve the purpose of click and I do not see Macintosh HD in the finder.

I tried to rename the home folder from the terminal like so:

`sudo mv my-old-home my-new-home`

But no luck. It says operation not permitted. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you want to fix, the odd behaviour of the new account, or the renaming?

Comment: The renaming of course

Comment: Might be easier to follow the instructions from Apple's support site (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548) on this, after making a backup of course.

Comment: Yeah but I am stuck at the step where I have to rename the directory. Because I don't see the HD in finder.

Comment: Can you use Shift-Cmd-G in Finder to open `/Users/` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has instructions on their support site on how to rename accounts, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548.

If you can't see your hard drive in the new account, an easy way out of this is using <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> to go to `/Users` directly and rename from there.